# Angular function not running in controller or binding to $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sure this is something simple, but I have tried this numerous ways with no result.

I have a factory that retrieves profile data from a simple endpoint, `/api/me`. It should return name, email, etc.... and it works fine for me profile page. However, my navbar seems to be a different story.

Some functions in the `navBarCtrl` seems to kick in, but it simply returns a boolean value. The function I REALLY want to kick in, seems to be inert.   It could be because it's waiting for some sort of event.

I attempted to use a broadcast when the auth service checks to see if the user is authenticated, but this didn't seem to do it either.

**First, the Node API endpoint. Probably not necessary, but just in case.**

```
app.get('/api/me', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.user, function(err, user) {
    res.send(user);
  });
});
```

**The Account factory.**

```
 angular
    .module('issuefy')
    .factory('Account', Account);

  Account.$inject = ['$http', 'LocalStorage'];

  function Account($http, LocalStorage) {

    return {
          getUser: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/me');
          },
          updateProfile: function(profileData) {
            return $http.put('/api/me', profileData);
          }
        };
```

**Now the controller.  Note, I attempt to do it two diffent ways.**

```
angular
      .module('issuefy')
      .controller('NavbarCtrl', NavbarCtrl);

    NavbarCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'LocalStorage', 'QueryService', '$auth', 'toastr', 'Account'];

    function NavbarCtrl($scope, $http, $location, LocalStorage, QueryService, $auth, toastr, Account) {

      $scope.getNavUser = function() {
        Account.getUser()
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.userNav = response.data;
          })
          .catch(function(response) {
            toastr.error(response.data.message, response.status);
          });
      };

      $scope.$on('user-authenticated', function(event, args) {
        Account.getUser()
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.userNav1 = response.data;
          })
          .catch(function(response) {
            toastr.error(response.data.message, response.status);
          });

});

      $scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
        return $auth.isAuthenticated();
      };
    }
```

**Now the template page.**

```
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="ion-ios7-pulse-strong"></i> Issuefy</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/#/">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-if="isAuthenticated()"><a href="/#/profile">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="/#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
        {{user.name}}
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="/#/logout">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/logout"><span ng-bind="userNav.email"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/logout"><span ng-bind="userNav1.email"></span></a></li>
        <li>{{userNav1.email}}</li>
        <li>
            <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
          <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
            <i class="fa fa-user">a {{userNav.email}} email</i></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

What am I missing? I am sure it's something simple.

Comment: Where is the code that generates the `user-authenticated` `$broadcast` or `$emit`?  The first method (`$scope.getNavUser = function() {`) isn't going to work, since you never actually call the function from anywhere.

Comment: Also - have you tried using promises?

Comment: @itamar `$http` is a promise.

Comment: @clais

I converted it to not use a function and it seemed to work.   I was under the impression functions got run once the controller was loaded, I guess I was incorrect.

If you turn your comment into an answer, ill accept it.

Comment: @Claies sorry - I should have clarified that I was referring to `$q`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know what return `$auth.isAuthenticated();`, is it sync or async? If it is async, then the expression `isAuthenticated()` maybe return the wrong value.

Comment: its async.  Returns true/false

Comment: maybe you should change it sync. you can try just return true or false.